# Summons in LaTeX

Tags: latex, document-classification

Is there any documentclass to write the summons in LaTeX? Documentclass Letter is inappropriate as it doesn't allow to write two columns on the begginig of the letter next to each other.

Comment: This question should be moved to [tex.se].

Comment: It seems fairly easy to replicate using the standard `article` class if it's like a regular letter. Perhaps you could include an example of a summons as an image (or ASCII art)...